# How to cascading implement Into trait for struct?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to blanket implement some convert trait for struct, to avoid unnecessary into() mess. Here is what I'm trying:

```rust
struct TypeA {}
struct TypeB {}

impl Into<TypeA> for TypeB {
    fn into(self) -> TypeA { unimplemented!(); }
}

impl<T: Into<TypeB>> Into<TypeA> for T {
    fn into(self) -> TypeA {
        unimplemented! ();
    }
}

struct TypeC {}

impl Into<TypeB> for TypeC {
    fn into(self) -> TypeB { unimplemented!(); }
}
```

But the compiler throw the following error

```
conflicting implementations of trait `std::convert::Into<TypeA>`
= note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
            - impl<T, U> Into<U> for T
              where U: From<T>;
```

So, how to blanket implement trait Into<TypeA> for any type that implement Into<TypeB>? Both TypeA, TypeB and TypeC is in local crate.

Comment: Don't impl `Into`, impl `From`.

Comment: Is there any reason for that? I want to avoid implement From for TypeA to avoid messing with its code.

Comment: I haven't dig into your code, this is just a general recommendation. There is a reason for that, yeah, since implementing `From` gives you `Into` for free but it does not work the other way around. This is also [noted in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.Into.html).

Comment: Note that `TypeB` implements `Into<TypeB>` thanks to the [blanket implementation of `From<T> for T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/convert/trait.From.html#impl-From%3CT%3E-12). Therefore your code offers two conflicting ways to convert `TypeB` into `TypeA`: either directly with your `impl Into<TypeA> for TypeB` or in two steps using the implicit `TypeB` → `TypeB` conversion and your `impl<T: Into<TypeB>> Into<TypeA> for T`.

Comment: There is also a second error about coherence that cannot be avoided without `From`.

Comment: The problem @Jmb correctly pointed out cannot be solved. If you get rid of the first `impl`, and switch to `From`, [it works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e418ef432cf4aacc3d5e76041a11d01a).

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler avoid the second way? TypeB -> TypeB doesn't make sense for me, compiler can always use the first way.

Comment: It's unsolvable in general case. For example, it could be not `TypeA -> TypeB` vs `TypeA -> TypeB -> TypeB`, but `TypeA -> TypeB1 -> TypeB` vs `TypeA -> TypeB2 -> TypeB`. Special-casing `Into<T> for T` is just not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to figure this out converting errors. For `TypeA`, I implemented `From` on `Into<TypeB>`. This allows anything that can convert `Into<TypeB>` to convert `Into<TypeA>`. That last test converts from `TypeC` to `TypeA`.

```rust
struct TypeA {
    name: String,
}
struct TypeB {
    name: String,
}
struct TypeC {
    name: String,
}

impl From<TypeC> for TypeB {
    fn from(c: TypeC) -> Self {
        TypeB { name: c.name }
    }
}

impl<T: Into<TypeB>> From<T> for TypeA {
    fn from(b: T) -> Self {
        let b = b.into();
        TypeA { name: b.name }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn c_to_b() {
        let c = TypeC {
            name: "C".to_string(),
        };
        let b: TypeB = c.into();
        assert_eq!("C", b.name.as_str())
    }

    #[test]
    fn b_to_a() {
        let b = TypeB {
            name: "B".to_string(),
        };
        let a: TypeA = b.into();
        assert_eq!("B", a.name.as_str())
    }

    #[test]
    fn c_to_a() {
        let c = TypeC {
            name: "C".to_string(),
        };
        let a: TypeA = c.into();
        assert_eq!("C", a.name.as_str())
    }
}
```